# how to install mongodb 3.2 version on ubuntu16.04

Tags: mongodb, installation

gaurav@mw:~$ sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package mongodb-org is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mongodb-org' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 0):

1) step upgrade php version 7.0 to 7.2

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install php7.2

2) step install mongo

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6

echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mongodb-org

sudo service mongod start

sudo service mongod status

sudo systemctl enable mongod

3) step install php driver

sudo apt-get install php-mongodb

4) step create test.php file in /var/www/html and type code and save it

5) step restart your computer